# Codeigniter : Grocery CRUD template doesn't exist

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

help ...I don't know where to start debugging

I downloaded codeigniter grocery crud . installed every requirement. Now its giving me . 

`grocery crud template doesn't exist`

libraries / grocery_crud.php 
at line 1388...

**EDIT**

```
if(!file_exists($this->theme_path.$this->theme.'/views/list_template.php'))
        {
            throw new Exception('The template does not exist. Please check your files and try again.', 12);
            die();
        }
```

It has something to do with this code..... I cant find list_template.php
even in the downloaded zip file

Comment: Did you load the template? $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');

Comment: yes I did....
still giving me the error....

Comment: Im using version 1.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dump($this->theme_path);` and `dump($this->theme);` and check what is the path in these objects if the root path is ok than check your directory that you have this file or not

```
your_project_folder\assets\grocery_crud\themes\datatables\views\list_template.php
your_project_folder\assets\grocery_crud\themes\flexigrid\views\list_template.php
```